# need book recommendation for advanced calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Next semester, I'll be taking a course in advanced calculus in my uni. I need a book which is beginner friendly, suitable for self study and most importantly covers the topics below.

1.The Real line and Euclidean space (ordered field, distance, Schwarz Inequality)

2. The topology of Euclidean space; open sets, Interior of a set, closed sets
3. The topology of Euclidean space; accumulation points, closure of a set, boundary of a set, sequences, completeness
4. Compact and Connected sets; compactness, the Heine-Borel theorem,
5. Compact and Connected sets; Nested set property, Path-connected sets, Connected sets
6. Continuous Mappings; continuity, Images of compact and connected sets
7. Continuous Mappings; operations on continuous mappings, the Boundedness of continuous functions on compact sets
8. Continuous Mappings; Uniform continuity
9. Uniform convergence; Differentiation and Integration of functions of one variable
10. Pointwise convergence, the Weierstrass M-test Uniform convergence
11. Integration and differentiation of series Uniform convergence;
12. The space of continuous functions,
13. The Arzela - Ascoli theorem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is writing to your university's math department out of the question? Did you look to see if there are online course pages for the course you'll be taking. That might list a textbook.

Comment: baby Rudin definitely covers all these topics (chapters 2,4,5,6,7); the only issue is it's not so beginner friendly. Charles C Pugh's real analysis text also covers these topics (but also more, he covers general metric space theory, just like Rudin), and some say it is less terse than Rudin (though I much preferred Rudin). Anyway, your question boils down to what substitutes there are for baby Rudin.